# D3 click event returning null attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using **D3 V4** and am trying to get the ID of the object that is clicked on. Heck, I'd love to see any attribute value returned (d, fill, class, etc). Instead I get null returned, no matter the attribute.  Code below.

```
    d3.json("0267_02_combine.json", function(json) {
    var features = json.features;

    var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection.fitExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]], json));

    svg.selectAll(".room")
        .data(json)
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "room")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill","lightblue")
        .attr("id", function(d){                
            return d.properties.loc;
        });

    svg.on("click", function() {
        console.log(d3.select(this)); //I see stuff!  Yay!
        console.log(d3.select(this).attr("fill")); //returns null
        console.log(d3.select(this).attr("id")); //returns null
        console.log(d3.select(this).attr("class")); //returns null

        var coords = d3.mouse(this);
        console.log(coords); //returns SVG coordinates
        console.log(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this))); //returns lat/lon

    })

});
```

Comment: Add some or all of 0267_02_combine.json please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the selected element you are attaching the click handler to has a fill, class or id?

Try adding your click handler to the path instead.

```js
d3.json("0267_02_combine.json", function(json) {
    var features = json.features;

    var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection.fitExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]], json));

    var path = svg.selectAll(".room")
        .data(json)
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "room")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill","lightblue")
        .attr("id", function(d){                
            return d.properties.loc;
        });

    path.on("click", function() {
        console.log(d3.select(this)); //I see stuff!  Yay!
        console.log(d3.select(this).attr("fill")); //returns null
        console.log(d3.select(this).attr("id")); //returns null
        console.log(d3.select(this).attr("class")); //returns null

        var coords = d3.mouse(this);
        console.log(coords); //returns SVG coordinates
        console.log(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this))); //returns lat/lon

    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Moving the on("click") to the path fixed it - thank you!!